# How can I convert an .mp3 to .flac?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, flac

Can someone tell me how I can convert an .mp3 audio file to .flac format using ffmpeg? I Googled extensively, but almost all resources point to converting .flac to .mp3, in such a way:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.flac" -ab 320k -map_meta_data 0:0 "output.mp3"
```

Comment: Did you try `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 output.flac` already?

Comment: Ummm, I just tried, and it works! Thanks. I thought that I will always have to put some metadata pertaining to the conversion while converting from one format to another.

Comment: I'll make an answer out of it then. Metadata might improve the conversion process but is not really required usually.

Comment: Converting from mp3 gets you worse quality, because mp3 is a lossy audio codec.

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comment: your MP3 file is lossy--meaning that it contains audio artifacts that may or may not be audible to you, but they're there.  FLAC is a lossless codec that can preserve the quality of an original recording so that it's exactly as it was e.g. on the CD.  But if you convert a poor quality MP3 to Flac, it's garbage in/garbage out--the poor quality doesn't magically get removed by converting to flac.

Comment: @RustyMonkey a more likely scenario would even be: garbage in, worse garbage out. ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Did you try `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 output.flac` already?